# Delay in $digest cycle

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement where closing a child window should trigger a method in the parent window. I'm using angular for development and I'd really like to do it the angular way.

Window 1 controller:

```
var abc = $window.open(url);
$scope.$watch('abc.closed', function() {
    // Do something when abc.close is true 
};
```

This works, but there is a delay in the process. When the child window closes, the listener is being triggered rather late, like 20-40 seconds later. 
What do you think is the issue, and also what's the best way to make this work?

I've seen other posts where people are using setInterval and watching for .closed but that would be a hack-ey way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using onbeforeunload event of the window

```
app.controller('yourCtrl', ['$window', function ($window) {
    $window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    //Your Service/Logic 
  }
]);
```

Comment: I have tried this before with no luck. I did a little more research on this. The problem was opening another domain with $window.open. Since it's a CSRF violation, it wouldn't let you set window objects.